# Eigenvalues of Maxwell or Lorentz Matrices

Tags: special-relativity, linear-algebra

It is actually a mathematical question. I encounter some problems on the properties of eigenvalues of Maxwell matrices $F^{\mu}_{\ \ \ \ \nu}$. If we are working in Euclidean space, the answer is easy, an anti-symmetric matrices always have eigenvalues like {i$\theta_1$,-i$\theta_1$,i$\theta_2$,-i$\theta_2$,....}. But in $\mathbf{R}^{1,n}$ spacetime, the Maxwell matries $F^{\mu}_{\ \ \ \ \nu}$ is no longer anti-symmetric. Denote the metric as $\eta_{\mu\nu} = \{-1,1,1,... \}$. $F^{\mu}_{\ \ \ \ \nu}$ will satisfy
\begin{equation}
F^T= -\eta F \eta.
\end{equation}
I guess the eigenvalues should be $\{ \sigma,-\sigma,i \theta_1,-i \theta_1,i\theta_2,-i\theta_2,...\}$ where $\sigma$ and $\theta$ are all real, but I do not whether that is true or how to prove that. Also, since one can always write a Lorentz matrix as
\begin{equation}
\Lambda = \exp F
\end{equation}
therefore the related (same) question is what are the general properties of an arbitary Lorentz matrix's eigenvalues.

Comment: What is a Maxwell matrix, and why are you looking for its eigenvalues?

Comment: The Maxwell matrix is just the electromagnetic field strength, or anti-symmetric matrix, sorry for not clarifying that. I ran into some calculations that need the eigenvalues of such a matrix.